# Prolog member function should work but it doesnt

Tags: prolog, unification

I am trying to check if a string is a working call that can be executed. To do this I parse the string, get the first word, and if it matches a database of predefined functions, it should succeed.
Q has the string, A will be used later, not now. Example of string is: append a and b.

```
is_uni(Q, A):-
    split_string(Q, " ", ",", [X|Y]),
    uni_db(Z),
    member(X, Z).

uni_db([
    append,
    member,
    append1
    ]).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `atom_codes/2` predicate to convert stings to atoms, in  example you need to convert  `"append"` to `append` in order to work.

```
is_uni(Q,A):-
    split_string(Q, " ", ",", [X|Y]),
    atom_codes(W,X),
    uni_db(Z),
    member(W, Z).
```

Example:

```
?- is_uni("append a and b",A).
true ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are confusing strings with atoms.

   `"append"` and `'append'`, a.k.a. `append`, are different. You can use `atom_string/2` to convert between them:

   ```
   ..., atom_string(A, X), ...
   ```
2. You are re-implementing built-in features.

   Why store commands in a list and iterate with `member/2`? Just define some facts:

   ```
   uni_db(append).
   uni_db(member).
   uni_db(append1).
   ```

   And then, you simply have to check whether `uni_db(A)`. This is   better  supported by an implementation and more likely to be done efficiently.

Comment: Or even better, put the "defined" predicates in a module and use `current_predicate(Module_name:Predicate_name)` to check if it is defined.